# if f is integer and satisfies $| f (z) | ≤ | z |^n$ then f must be a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Show that if f is integer and satisfies an inequality of the form
$| f (z) | ≤ | z |^n$ for some $n ∈ \mathbb N$ and for all $| z |$ big enough,
then f must be a polynomial.

I know that since f is integer it's equal to a power series centered at zero$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$
but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Do you mean $f$ is analytic?

Comment: Am I right that you mean $f$ being entire function?

Comment: Look at Cauchy's inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to use the Cauchy integral formula for the $n$-th derivative
$$
f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta
$$
for sufficiently large $R$.

Comment: the last thing I get is $ |f^{(n)}(0)| ≤ \frac{n! |z|^n}{r^n}$  @richrow